# apt upgrade fails with libglib/libgdk error

Tags: apt, 18.04

Having an issue updating Ubuntu 18.04 install

```
sudo apt update
```

works fine, then

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

fails with

```
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (= 6= 2.48.0) but 2.56.3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

then running:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

gives

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0
```

followed by:

```
dpkg: warning: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 14881 package 'libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:amd64':
 'Depends' field, reference to 'libglib2.0-0':
 implicit exact match on version number, suggest using '=' instead
dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 14881 package 'libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:amd64':
 'Depends' field, reference to 'libglib2.0-0': version contains ' '
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

edit:

```
$ apt-cache policy libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:amd64 libglib2.0-0
libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:
  Installed: 2.36.11-2
  Candidate: 2.36.11-2
  Version table:
     2.36.11-2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2.36.11-2 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libglib2.0-0:
  Installed: 2.56.3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
  Candidate: 2.56.3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 2.56.3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.56.1-2ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

edit2:
after re-enabling the package sources

```
$ sudo apt update
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]
Hit:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]   
Fetched 177 kB in 0s (384 kB/s)                                                
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
122 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

then

```
$ sudo apt full-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (= 6= 2.48.0) but 2.56.3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

$ apt-cache policy libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:amd64 libglib2.0-0
libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:
  Installed: 2.36.11-2
  Candidate: 2.36.11-2
  Version table:
     2.36.11-2 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2.36.11-2 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libglib2.0-0:
  Installed: 2.56.3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
  Candidate: 2.56.3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 2.56.3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.56.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
     2.56.1-2ubuntu1 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:amd64 libglib2.0-0` to the question.

Comment: For me it seems that you have not enabled *bionic-security* and *bionic-updates* pockets of repositories. Please [enable them](https://askubuntu.com/a/192388/66509) and retry with `sudo apt update`, `sudo apt full-upgrade`.

Comment: Try my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks - I get the same error as before: "dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 14881 package 'libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:amd64':
" - the line in questions reads "Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14), libglib2.0-0 (6= 2.48.0), libjpeg8 (>= 8c), libpng16-16 (>= 1.6.2-1), libtiff5 (>= 4.0.3), libx11-6, shared-mime-info, libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common (= 2.36.11-2)"

Comment: Then install Aptitude with `sudo apt-get install aptitude` and then run `sudo aptitude dist-upgrade` to fix the problem. Or run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I fixed it by editing the /var/lib/dpkg/status file and changing libglib2.0-0(6=2.48.0) to read (=2.48.0)  - then did an apt update/upgrade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to download both problematic packages and then force their installation with:

```
apt-get download libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0=2.36.11-2 libglib2.0-0=2.56.3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
sudo dpkg -i --force-all lib*.deb
```

Comment: Thanks still get the error: 
dpkg: warning: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 14881 package 'libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:amd64':
 'Depends' field, reference to 'libglib2.0-0':
 implicit exact match on version number, suggest using '=' instead
dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 14881 package 'libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:amd64':
 'Depends' field, reference to 'libglib2.0-0': version contains ' '

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by editing the /var/lib/dpkg/status file and changing libglib2.0-0(6=2.48.0) to read (=2.48.0) - then did an apt update/upgrade